# Hook up click event after AppendMenu of 3rd party Application

Tags: c#, wpf, hook, pinvoke, user32

i'm trying to add a new MenuItem using DLL Fucntions imported of the user32.dll using DLLImort to a third party application out of my WPF app.

No I'd like to get the click event of the newly generated MenuItem. Any ideas?
Here's the code so far. I know there are functions of SetWindowHookEx or something else, but I'm stuck.

It's some test code and not bulletproofed..

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetMenu(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSubMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hMenu);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool InsertMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uItem, bool
    fByPosition, [In] ref MENUITEMINFO lpmii);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DrawMenuBar(IntPtr hWnd);

    internal const UInt32 MIIM_FTYPE = 0x00000100;
    internal const UInt32 MF_STRING = 0x00000000;
    internal const UInt32 MF_OWNERDRAW = 0x00000100;

    const uint MF_POPUP = 0x00000010;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, MenuFlags uFlags, uint uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreatePopupMenu();

    [Flags]
    public enum MenuFlags : uint
    {
        MF_STRING = 0,
        MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400,
        MF_SEPARATOR = 0x800,
        MF_REMOVE = 0x1000,
        MF_POPUP = 0x00000010,
    }



    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MENUITEMINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fMask;
        public uint fType;
        public uint fState;
        public uint wID;
        public IntPtr hSubMenu;
        public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
        public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
        public IntPtr dwItemData;
        public string dwTypeData;
        public uint cch;
        public IntPtr hbmpItem;

        // return the size of the structure
        public static uint sizeOf
        {
            get { return (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO)); }
        }
    }



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        createMenuEntry();
    }

    private void createMenuEntry()
    {
        Process[] proceses = Process.GetProcessesByName("spotify");
        Process process = proceses.Where(e => e.MainWindowTitle == "Spotify").First();
        IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
        IntPtr mainMenu = GetMenu(handle);

        int mainMenuItemCount = GetMenuItemCount(mainMenu);

        AppendMenu(mainMenu, MenuFlags.MF_STRING, 555, "TestEntry");
    }



    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        //HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        //source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        // Handle messages...

        Debug.WriteLine((int)wParam);

        if (((int)wParam == 555))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click");
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

}
```

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is to put down the C# and understand how the native menu API works. Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553.aspx

I strongly recommend that you create a new C++ project and write a simple program to add a menu and respond to clicks.

The key information is found in the documentation I linked to, with my emphasis:

> When the user chooses a command item, **the system sends a command message to the window that owns the menu**. If the command item is on the window menu, the system sends the WM_SYSCOMMAND message. Otherwise, it sends the WM_COMMAND message.

You need to intercept that message. I suspect that means to need to use a global `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook. That's going to need an unmanaged DLL to implement the hook.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But wouldn't it be possible to create a c++ dll project to create the menu and implement the hook? And listen for an event in the C# project?

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: :D okay. Tanks. Thought of implementing the wohle app using c++